# If $\sum a_k$ converges, does $\sum(a_{k+1}- 2 a_{k+3})$ converge as well?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> If $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ is convergent with value $s$, what about $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ where $b_k=a_{k+1}- 2 a_{k+3}$?

My reasoning:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n b_k=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^na_{k+1}-2a_{k+3}
$$
Within the sum we are only dealing with finitely many terms, we can split up the sum and take the limit afterwards:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n b_k=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_{k+1}- \sum_{k=0}^n 2a_{k+3} \right) $$
Now we want to get $s$ in here, the value of our sum, we need to do some index juggling, since our sum is not of the right form yet.
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_{k} - a_0- 2\sum_{k=0}^n a_{k}  +2a_0 + 2a_1+2a_2\right) $$
Here we applied an index shift, but then we need to compensate for the terms that we added to the sum, we finally apply the limit and get:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k=s +a_0-2s+2a_1+2a_2= a_0+2a_1+2a_2 -s $$

Did that all make sense, is my reasoning correct? 
conclusion: it converges as we computed the exact value.

Comment: If $\sum x_n = X \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sum y_n = Y \in \mathbb{R}$,  then $\sum (x_n + y_n) =X+ Y$, so yes, the reasoning is correct.

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: Please provide your answers in the answer section. This way the question does not stay open.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write this in the answer section so that the question does not remain open.

The reasoning looks fine and correct to me.